# Copy multiple files by name from different folders to single folder?

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

I have 10000's of file in a "ingenious" folder structure offered by my work. I need to merge these files by date order, to do this I need these files in the same map so I can sort it and run a simple command `copy *.log merged.log`.

Is there a way I can go up in folder structure, search for these files by part of there name and copy them to a single folder?

Folder structure looks like this but is pretty much random too.

```
date/<files>
date/backup/<files>
date/backup/kastX/<files>
date/backup/kastX/backup<files>
```

I have many `dates`, more `backup` and even more `kastX` folders. File names come like this:

```
kast9_3055_// +date (not important now)
kast9_3056_// +date (not important now)
kast18_6021_// +date (not important now)
```

Files come in `.bak` and `.log`. I should be good if I can `copy kast9_3055*.*` from all deeper lying folders to a single separate folder.

Comment: When you talk about date, do you mean the last modified date?

Comment: @and31415 yes but since the files contain date in test as well I could sort by name too.

Comment: You might flatten the main folder structure by recursively copying all `.log` files in a different folder, and then merge them.

Comment: @and31415 that would fix it.  How to flatten?

Comment: For example like this: `for /r "X:\source" %G in (*.log) do @copy "%~fG" "Y:\destination"`

Comment: @and31415 Can you do that in the CMD prompt? Can you make this a bit more detailed answer? If i am able to flatten the map structure like this it will probably fix my problem, or at least for a big part.